# Remove Duplicate Based on three Columns MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Trying to remove duplicate based on three column like query will not find duplicate based on single column it will concatenate three column then remove duplicate rows based on the merge column.

I would appreciate if someone can share an easiest way of achieving this. I know this is not an appropraiote way but tried and its not working

```
Select concat(col1, col2, col3,) as newCol distinct newcCol from Table2
```

I know how to remove the table duplicate based on multiple columns using Excel VBA but do not know how to achieve this using `mysql`

```
Sub DelDupl()

    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Table name is Table2 in Mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVpk0.png)

**Sample Data**

```
CREATE TABLE Table2(
col1 INT,
col2 varchar(10),
col3 INT,
col4 varchar(10),
col5 varchar(10),
col6 varchar(10),
col7 varchar(10));
INSERT INTO Table2 (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7)
VALUES ('1','A','123456','data1','data1','data1','data1'),
('2','B','78910','data2','data2','data2','data2'),
('3','C','45698','data3','data3','data3','data3'),
('1','A','123456','data1','data1','data1','data1'),
('2','B','78910','data2','data2','data2','data2'),
('3','C','45698','data3','data3','data3','data3'),
('4','D','85969','data5','data5','data5','data5');
```

Comment: Sample data would help us better understand the exact problem.

Comment: I have added sample data in my question.

Comment: Does `SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(col1, col2, col3) AS newCol FROM Table2` work?

Comment: It only shows the Merged Column, how to show the complete table without duplicates. Like col1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Comment: Just ignore the rest of columns for thier data, but i want to keep these columns as, it is test data. @P.Salmon

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table2 AS t
GROUP BY t.col1, t.col2, t.col3;
```

[GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) is normally used for aggregating functions(count, sum, max, etc), but will do the job for your purpose.

**Edit:**
Ok, since you actually need to `delete` duplicates, thats a bit more complicated, but it's possible. First we need to somehow discriminate duplicate rows, so we will temporary add a primary key. Then execute `delete` statement, while joining the table on itself to find duplicated rows. And lastly drop the primary key column we added.

- add primary key column, we need some discrimination for duplicates

```
ALTER TABLE `table2` ADD COLUMN id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

- join table on itself to get duplicates and delete them

```
DELETE t1
FROM `table2` t1
INNER JOIN `table2` t2
ON t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2 AND t1.col3 = t2.col3
WHERE t1.id < t2.id;
```

- drop the primary key column

```
ALTER TABLE `table2` DROP COLUMN id;
```

As a note, the join is done on the columns which define duplication(col1, col2, col3) in your case. You can execute all 3 queries at once, just be sure you **really need** this data **gone**.

Comment: This will only group by the records by the three columns if the other columns are dependent from the other (aka ('1','A','123456','data1bis','data1','data1','data1') will break the query). Moreover, it will not remove the duplicates.

Comment: @dcolazin What do you mean it won't remove duplicates? I tested the query with provided example data, and it does remove duplicate rows. Also according to the question, rows are considered duplicate by columns `col1, col2, col3`, and there is nothing about some columns depending on other columns.

Comment: You need to delete the duplicated rows from the DB, don't just show a cleaned version of the data. Aka from (apples, bananas, pears, mango, apples, bananas) you want (apples, bananas, pears, mango) in the db (not in a select).

Comment: Yes you are right i want to remove duplicate based on `Concatenate(Col1,col2,Col3)` then remove duplicate rows. But when i run the query it works but when i use `Select * from table2` then duplicate data was not deleted ? It should be deleted from `table2` @Chaosfire

Comment: @Husnain See the edit, i added how to delete duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there is no way to establish which to keep so I suggest you set up a staging table with a compound key, load it , truncate your existing table and load it from the staging table